# How to get local storage value when component Did mount?

Tags: reactjs

I have issue in getting `localStorage` value when page loaded

if I refresh the page it is working.

how do i get the `localStorage` value when page loaded.

I have two files one is utils.js in this file I have declared a object

```
export const user = {
      id: window.localStorage.userId
    };
```

Another one is userDetails.js in this page i have getting a value on

```
import {user} from './utils';

componentDidMount=() => {
   console.log(user.id);//for the first time its getting null .when i refresh the page value is updated
}
```

Answer (score 2):

// Use state and props concept for data flow in react
// Util.js

```
import React, Component from 'react'; 
class Utils extends Component{
        state = {
            user: {
                 id: window.localStorage.userId
            }
        } 
}  
export default Utils;
```

```
//UserDetails.js
import React, Component from 'react';
import Utils from './Utils';
class UserDetails extends Component{
    componentDidMount=() => {
        console.log(this.props.user.id);//One time
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        if(this.props.user !== newProps.user)
            console.log(newProps.user); // Each time props changes
    }
}
```

Also, redux can be used for global state management
https://redux.js.org/
I hope this helps.